# Checking to see if file is open and If so write the error to the access database

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a method to check to see if a files is open and if it is open write the error to an access database. I have the file open, it reads the try but never gets to the catch ex as exception so that it writes to the database. It goes back to my copy method that I have created and goes to the catch exception there where it sees that the files is open.

```
  Private Sub IsFileOpen(nFile As String)
        Dim stream As FileStream
        Dim sqlError As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        sqlError = conn.CreateCommand

        Dim docName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(nFile)
        Dim fileName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(nFile)
        Dim processDate As String = Date.Now
        Dim errorNum As String = ""

        Try
            stream = File.Open(nFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            stream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            If TypeOf ex Is Exception Then
                errorNum = ex.Message
                sqlError.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblDocumentCopyError ([DocName], [FileName], [ProcessDate], [ErrorNumber]) " _
                                    & " VALUES (@DocName, @FileName, @ProcessDate, @ErrorNumber) "

                sqlError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocName", docName)
                sqlError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName)
                sqlError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProcessDate", processDate)
                sqlError.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ErrorNumber", errorNum)
                sqlError.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show(vbCrLf & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Took me a while to find the question in your post.  Sounds like the file isn't locked from read access.

Comment: file is locked I have it open my code never reaches the goes to end try the it will go to my next method and the it catches the error there stating the file is open with error # 55

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need a `Finally` containing `If stream IsNot Nothing Then stream.Dispose()`.

Comment: I am never getting to the catch statement if the file is open which I want it to catch so than I can record the error in a database.

Comment: Well, how is the file locked?

Comment: If you can open the file for read access, which you obviously can if no exception is thrown, then the file is not locked for read access.  The fact that you think it is doesn't change that.  Also, if you are trying to catch the exception thrown in a specific circumstance then you should be catching the specific type of exception that will be thrown, not `Exception`.  Also, what is that `If` statement for?  You can't catch anything that isn't an exception so checking whether it's an exception is pointless.